# Advantages/disadvantages to sign-in with Twitter, Facebook, and Google?

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, registration

What are the advantages and disadvantages of implementing social sign-on on my website using these providers:

- Facebook
- Google
- Twitter

I've noticed that certain websites employ one and not the other, or two but not three. Is this just a personal decision, or are there specific considerations that I should keep in mind (e.g. Facebook doesn't give me a user's email address, Twitter doesn't give me contact information)?

Comment: Note: Facebook gives you the email adress! But you'll have to define that, and the user has to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought and problem a while a go, the thing is:

- In the end it comes up to you and what Information you need from an User.
- A problem for me in the past was that twitter for example doesn't provide a users email address while facebook does. So you must either set up a dummy email or extent the signup so a user must enter his email. etc. etc. etc.
- A problem would also be what you application is about, if you count on social interaction and social traffic via shares etc. etc. a social authentication wouldn't be bad.

Google isn't represented much in authentication and interaction because.. you know.. Google+, A network for Google Employees.

Jokes aside, it's 'almost always' a good think to implement Social Authentication for the reason that Signup Rates can slightly increase. Of Course you should judge for your self and define your needs.

Hope that helps a bit.

(I would recommend you give a [look at this](http://blog.mailchimp.com/social-login-buttons-arent-worth-it/) )